# Setting up multicast between two apps on same computer

Tags: ubuntu, networking, multicast

I have two Java apps running on the same computer. Each one uses the IP address of the computer (the IP on the `enpXXX` interface). App1 sends a packet to App2 using multicast, but it doesn't seem to actually be sending the packet.

What I've tried:

1. I used *wireshark* to see if the multicast packet is going from App1 to the multicast address. I don't see that happening. But I know it's not a code problem because I got everything to work on windows.
2. I added a route where `destination=224.0.0.0` (multicast address) and `Interface=enpXXX`.
3. The default gateway for everything is `0.0.0.0`. So I thought maybe the packets are getting stuck on the gateway. I read `0.0.0.0` is used if there are no hops. I'm not sure if routing to a multicast counts as a hop. So I added another route where `destination=0.0.0.0`, `gateway=enpXXX` address, and `interface=enpXXX`. That way anything on the gateway goes back to the `enpXXX` interface.
4. I ran ifconfig and checked the config of the `enpXXX` interface. It is up, and it also has `MULTICAST` in the configuration.

So far, none of this has worked. I've gotten most of these ideas from reading other posts. Is there anything else I can check to troubleshoot? Or are there any good examples on how to do this properly?

Comment: I do not know how java handles multicast. In a bsd-socket environment you would 1.) add an address the desired multicast group via 'setsockopt', 2.) set up a udp socket with port XY 3.) send data to the multicast group port XY. You may not receive anything if you are listening to the same address and port with 2 applications simultaneously, but you may add a 2nd ip to the host, and bind/listen on two addresses with the same port though. Also keep in mind:packets, which do not leave the host, may be passed via the 'lo' interface on linux. You will not see them on the enpXXX interfaces then.

Comment: actually, *on linux* looped back multicast packets appear on the same interface (ie: not lo) which can cause problems with firewalls (which can be solved by marking the packet). It's usually controlled with something like `setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, "\1", 1)` (which is common for all BSD socket *nixes)

Comment: @A.B So it will show traffic on something like 127.0.1.1 but not 127.0.0.1 (lo)? Because I think I'm seeing that now. I see multicast traffic leaving one app (127.0.1.1) to the 224.x.x.x multicast address. But I cant get the traffic from that multicast address to the second app also on 127.0.1.1.

Comment: considering 127.0.1.1 is already routed on lo (the whole 127.0.0.0/8 is on lo), I'm not sure this can work as intended for multicast.  Disable your firewall entirely and try a normal source address (or else maybe see https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v5.4#n1220).

Comment: Maybe show the code, or at least essential `strace` output.